# How can I make a class which has a public method that cannot be inherited by its sub-class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I want to make a class `A` like this

```
class A:
    @someDecorator
    def f(self):
        print('A.f')

    def g(self):
        print('A.g')
```

And I can use it like this

```
a = A()
a.f() #prints A.f
a.g() #prints A.g
```

But if I declare a class `B` as a subclass of `A`, attribute `f` of class `B` will become invisible

```
class B(A):
    pass

b = B()
b.g() #prints A.g
b.f() #error: no such attribute
```

How can I make this `@someDecorator`?

Comment: While you have some options to just  overwrite the name or implement a special `__getattr__`, consider that what you trying g to do is not how object inheritance should work.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to check `__class__` of the method, and return if it matches `A`.

```
def disable_method(func):
   def func_wrapper(name):
       if name.__class__ == A:
           return func(name)
       else:
           raise AttributeError("Cannot call inherited method")
   return func_wrapper

class A:
    @disable_method
    def f(self):
        print('A.f')

    def g(self):
        print('A.g')

class B(A):
    pass

a = A()
a.f()
#A.f

b = B()
b.f()
#AttributeError: Cannot call inherited method
```

Edit: Looking at this again it is possible to check whether the method's class has a superclass by `__bases__`. It should work as long as its being used as a decorator.

```
def disable_method(func):
    def func_wrapper(name):
        if name.__class__.__bases__ == object:
            return func(name)
        else:
            raise AttributeError("Cannot call method from superclass")
    return func_wrapper
```

Comment: But I want this decorator working on different classes. How can I do that with this approach?

Comment: And I don't want to add a parameter to this decorator for simplicity.

Comment: Hm, make dedicated decorators? Or just overwrite the method.

Comment: @Home3 looking at this again I think you can make a generic decorator by checking its superclass by `__bases__`. It should work being just a decorator.